# Unable to connect to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, go

I'm playing around with `Golang` and trying to connect to MS SQL. I'm using `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` package and `sqlx` for this purpose.
But I'm getting error: `Unable to open tcp connection with host 'localhost:1433': dial tcp [::1]:1433: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.
I'm completely sure that everything with database itself since it's perfectly working with my.Net project.
Here is is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

type Excursion struct {
    Id   int            `db:"id"`
    Name sql.NullString `db:"name"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("sqlserver", "server=localhost;user id=DESKTOP-H74S9IT\\andrey.shedko;database=Flex;connection timeout=30;")
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    rows, err := db.Queryx("SELECT Id, Name FROM dbo.Excursions")
    for rows.Next() {
        var item Excursion
        err = rows.StructScan(&item)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf(
            "%d - %s:  %s\n===================\n",
            item.Id,
            item.Name.String,
        )
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Could you advice please what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you need to activate TCP.

More info: [Enable TCP/IP Network Protocol for SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx)

[image]

[image]

<sup>Images source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/includes/media/virtual-machines-sql-server-connection-tcp-protocol/enable-tcp.png and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/includes/media/virtual-machines-sql-server-connection-tcp-protocol/restart-sql-server.png</sup>

Comment: note restart of the sql server service is also required after network config change to enable tcpip as mentioned in the answer above. i had missed it.

Comment: also note if sql server is installed with integrated security without creating sa account - connection string may look like this. `"server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=True;port=1433;database=northwind"` without user id and password